# Heater from France with blue, black, brown wires

Tags: wiring, plug

I have just bought an oil heater from Screwfix.  It is a French appliance supplied without a plug.  I've just realised the wires are blue, brown and black. Would anyone know how I go about connecting a UK plug?

Comment: ask the seller ..

Answer (score 2):

Blue is Neutral.

One of brown and black is Live, the other is the pilot wire, that is used to control all heaters in the house with an optional programmer/clock/thermostat/etc. If you don't use that, it is fine to leave it unconnected and properly terminated (ie, no copper strands flapping around).

Usually which wire is which is which is written on the back of the heater.

Live = "Phase"

Neutral = "Neutre"

Pilot = "Pilote"

Just connect Live and Neutral to your socket.

Comment: No PE wire in an oil heater? they have found a way to make them double insulated?

Comment: Yes, they're pretty much all double insulated these days.